# Change logger level for single class through system property

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback

Is there a way to change the *logging level* of a class using a System Property in the launcher? I want to be able to easily and quickly change the debug level of a class depending on which class I'm working on. Being able to do it at launch time with something like `-Dcom.example.package.myclass.logger.level=TRACE`
or
`-Dcom.slf4j.trace=com.example.package.myclass`

would be very useful.

I'm using slf4j/logback but i'm also interested in a way to do it in log4j

I know how to change the level programatically, but i don't want to have to change code, just the launcher

If it's relevant, I'm using a configuration file `logback-test.xml`

If it's not possible, is there another trick to do this without changing code or having to pollute the clean xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[update]

I re-read your question and I think we can get closer.

Add the following to your logback.xml:

```
  <if condition='isDefined("com.slf4j.trace")'>
    <then>
      <logger name="${com.slf4j.trace}" level="TRACE"/>
    </then>
  </if>
```

Add the Codehaus Janino and Apache commons-compiler jars to your classpath as described [on the Logback Setup page](http://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino).

Now you launch your app with

```
-Dcom.slf4j.trace=com.example.package.MyClass
```

Comment: this works nicely, thanks!
the one problem is the conditional config requires two extra dependencies

Comment: True. It's always something :)

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas from logback docs:

> Logback-classic can scan for changes in its configuration file and
>   automatically reconfigure itself when the configuration file changes.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" > 
  ...
</configuration>
```

Also, you can specify the location of the default configuration file as a system property:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1
```

So it's even more convenient than you described it.

Comment: The goal of reconfiguration scan is different: it's so that you can change the level of a running application. That's not what i want, i want to change the level before starting it but without touching the configuration file since if i modify it while testing, the changes will make eclipse want to commit the file

Comment: Still you can use `java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1` and mark this config file as `ignored` in you source code repository. This is similar to what you want.

Comment: ok, i see your point: Creating a working log configuration that i don't commit. It's not ideal but it might be my only chance

Comment: You can also think about implementing that by your own. In some static init block you can scan for such a properties and set logging level pragmatically.